# Can't reconcile this use of Retrofit with the docs

Tags: java, android, json, http, retrofit2

I have inherited some code that contains this use of Retrofit:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("checkin?")
Call<AppVersionResponse> checkAppVersion(@Query("MRN") String mrn, @Body Patient patient);
```

Questions:

1. What is the "?" doing at the end of "`checkin`?". By my reading, this will produce **two** question marks in the request (the second coming from the `@Query`). Perhaps this is tolerated by HTTP but it seems wrong to me.
2. What is supposed to happen when the `Call`'s `@Query` parameter is followed by the `@Body` parameter? The docs say that `@Body` allows specifying the *entire body* of the request.

AFAIK, this code was working but as a Retrofit noob I can't figure out why, or if it needs attention.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: I don't know if that ? Is part of retrofit syntax, I guess it isn't so I think it's more a question of url rewriting on the server.

Question 2: Since you are sending parameters by Post, these parameters are in the header, so it's possible to send parameters in the header among with body content. Later in the server you can check the parameter and decide how to process the body for example. It's not the best approach but it's possible.

Comment: Docs say that the String in '@POST' is appended to the base URL. And the examples for '@Query' show it producing a "?", as you would expect. Thus it appears that "??" would be produced. By URL rewriting do you mean that the server just disregards the second one?

Comment: '@Query produces a ? only when you send parameters by GET, because parameters are appended to the url. When you are using post, parameters are sent inside the header. The String in 'POST' is appended in the url but since you use post method yo will not append the '@Query parameters to the url. 

For example, your call will produce a request to http://baseurl.com/checkin? inside the header is the parameter mrn.

If your change your call to '@GET("checkin?") your call will produce a call to http://baseurl.com/checkin??mrn=some_value. I guess that server changes checkin? for something else...